# Find $a, b, c$ values from function $y=ax^2-bx+c$ and minimum value $D$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The problem reads like this:

> The quadratic function which takes the value $41$ at $x = -2$ and $20$ at $x = 5$, is: $y = Ax^2-Bx+C$
>
> The minimum value for this function is: $D$

I order it like this:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{1}
A(-2)^2-B(-2)+C=41\\
A(5)^2-B(5)+C=20
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{1}
4A+2B+C=41\\
25A-5B+C=20
\end{array}
\right.
$$
And try to solve it as a system of equations. But I'm stuck there. In fact, I'm not even sure if I'm approaching it the correct way.

**EDIT**
I got the answers for each variable, I just don't know the procedure to get them.

A=3; B=12; C=5; D=-7

Answer (score 1):

You need three equations to solve a linear system with three unknowns. The minimum equation will give you a third equation, assuming you are given the value of $D$ (or are allowed to express the other three vars in terms of $D$). Recall the vertex of a parabola occurs at $x=-b/2a$, or $x=B/2A$ in your case. Since there is a minimum, this must be it, as a parabola only has one turning point.

Comment: But I'm not given the value of D

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the first equation from the second and get
$$
21A-7B=-21
$$
which gives $B=3A+3$ and so, substituting in the first equation,
$$
C=41-4A-2B=41-4A-6A-6=35-10A
$$

You are also given that the function has a minimum, so $A>0$. This minimum is taken at $x=B/(2A)$, so the minimum value is
$$
D=A\frac{B^2}{4A^2}-B\frac{B}{2A}+C=-\frac{B^2}{4A}+C=
-\frac{(3A+3)^2}{4A}+35-10A
$$
but the information is insufficient for determining $D$.

Comment: Hmm but with that I still can't determine the exact values.

Comment: @AndresR You can't determine the minimum value with just two conditions, you need three.

Answer (score 0):

The question as given in the post does not make sense as the value can be as small as you want, according to this [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eehcsvbwsr) graph.

However, if we add in the restriction that $A, B, C$ are all positive integers, then we can solve the problem. Following on from egreg's solution, we need $A>0, B = 3A+3 ≥ 0$, which gives $A > -1$, and $C = 35-10A > 0$ which gives $A < 3.5$. Combining these two inequalities gives $-1 < A < 3.5$.

As $A$ increases, the value of $C$ decreases, which means the minimum value of the function decreases. Therefore, the maximum value of $A$ is $3$, which means $B=3(3)+3=12$, and $C = 35-10(3)=5$. The vertex thus has $x$-coordinate $\frac{-b}{2a} = \frac{3(3)+3}{2(3)} = 2$, so the minimum value is equal to $ax^2+bx+c = 3(2)^2- 12 \cdot (2) + 5 = -7$, exactly as described in your question.